# C# winforms multi language resx file not embedded into assembly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a winforms multi language application for which i've created a folder with 2 .resx files (ex: Resources.en.resx).
The application works fine in debug mode (retrieves different string values based on the selected language), but, after running the installer and eventually the app, it crashes, returning the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "-ProjectName-.LanguageResources.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "-ProjectName-" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

The properties for the language resx files are:
build action - embedded resource,
copy to output directory - do not copy,
customtool - ResXFileCodeGenerator

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use build-in localization logic in this case, write your own localizer which gets data from your embedded resources explicit

Comment: Thank you for your response. If my understanding is fine, i belive i treat this case in a static class with the following code:
`public static CultureInfo languageCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"); 
        public static ResourceManager resManager = new ResourceManager("ProjectName.LanguageResources.Resources", typeof(Main).Assembly);`

This works fine, until the moment i install & run

Comment: Yes, exactly - I've added code in the answer. After that you can even write an extension for string type to do something like "some_text".Localize();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

namespace LogWizard
{
    static class Localizer
    {
        private static ResourceManager MainResourse = null;

        public static void InitLocalizedResource(string LanguagePrefix, string ResourseBase, string Delimeter = "_")
        {
            string FullResourseName = ResourseBase;
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            var ResList = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ToList();

            if (ResList.
                Where(x => x.Equals(FullResourseName + Delimeter + LanguagePrefix + ".resources"))
                .Count() == 1)
                FullResourseName += Delimeter + LanguagePrefix;

            MainResourse = new ResourceManager(FullResourseName, assembly);
        }

        public static string Localize(this string str)
        {
            return GetString(str);
        }

        public static string GetString(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                if (MainResourse == null) 
                    return name;

                string result = MainResourse.GetString(name);
                return (result == null) ? name : result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return name;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Somewhere at start:

```
Localizer.InitLocalizedResource("en", "LogWizard.Resources.lang");
```

Somewhere in code:

```
var localized = "text_item".Localize();
```

Moreover, this approach allows to change program localization at runtime

Comment: Thank you very much Alek for the elaborate answer

Comment: Apparently, in my case, the problem was related to the flexera install shield, which did not included the localized resources, and after including that to the installer it now works fine. 
Let that alone, your implementation also seems to work just as well so thank you again (answer accepted).